# How can i loop through json data?

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to learn node.js but at some point i got stuck.
 This is my json input :
[
 {
   "FIELD1": "name",
   "FIELD2": "id"},
{
 "FIELD1": "abc",
   "FIELD2": "12"}]

How can i loop through this,i tried 'for' but it didn't work.
can any one help ?

Comment: show the code, you've already tried.

Comment: for(var jsondata in body){
console.log(jsondata);
}

This returns 0,1,2...as output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you can use 3 opportunities here:

- Array.forEach (shown below)
- usual for loop ( `for(let t = 0; t < data.length; t++) { ... }` )
- ES7 for of loop (`for(const el of data) { ... }`)

Assuming you have such data:

```
const data = [ { "FIELD1": "name", "FIELD2": "id"}, { "FIELD1": "abc", "FIELD2": "12"}];
```

You can loop through it:

```
data.forEach(el => console.log(el));
```

The one you've tried: `for(let prop in obj)` is used to iterate through objects, not arrays.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to loop over an array of json objects, so you could just

```
  for(let i= 0; i < object.length; i++){
        //access your object fields
        console.log(object[i].FIELD1);
        console.log(object[i].FIELD2);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

well, first of all you are looping over an array. That you can do.

For looping over a json, you can either get the keys. I believe `.keys()`.

I also believe you can do `for(var x in json){}`